# How many ethereum can I mine with 6 * Radeon RX 480 GDDR5 8GB mining rig?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools, gpu

I planned to create a mining rig with 6 * Radeon RX 480 GDDR5 8GB cards ? I just want to know how many Ethereum I can mine per day if i use it 24hours continuously..

The mining rig is expected to get 150 MH/s , So could anyone tell me how many I will mine per day if i join Dwarfpool?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calculator like these?
https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/eth
http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/ethereum-mining-calculator